# C# 9 top-level programs without csproj?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

One feature of coming C# 9 is so called top-level programs. So that you could just write the following without classes.

```
using System;

Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

and `dotnet run` will launch it for you.

It works for me, but only if I also add a `.csproj` file like the one below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Is there a way to skip `.csproj` from the picture? :) So that there's just a single `Program.cs` file and nothing more.

Comment: You can run the program with `csi.exe`. I know that's not what you were looking for, and it's not a 9.0 future, but perhaps it will be useful

Comment: Don't worry, we don't normally count the contents of csproj when golfing... 

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No there isn't. The `csproj` file, explains to the compiler what kind of output to make.

It also references any needed libraries, in your case that is the SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj

> Metapackages are implicitly referenced based on the target framework(s) specified in the `<TargetFramework>` or `<TargetFrameworks>` property of your project file.

Without it, net core would miss information on what to build and how. You wouldn't even have the references to `System` Namespaces available.

Comment: So it would be correct to assume there's no command line arguments for `dotnet run` that would substitute, and make redundant, the csproj?

Comment: You can check the options yourself here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build No way to build it. Even if there was, there would be no way to run MsBuild, which needs either a csproj or an sln and csproj.

Comment: It is possible to write exensions for the .NET CLI so technically it is possible to create an extension you use instead of run that outputs a .csproj file with defaults or based on arguments supported by the extension.  Not sure I see the value in that though, other than perhaps to enforce some internal policy

Comment: @Athanasios MSbuild presumably still needs an actual class and all the other boilerplate and that's added in a pre-build step. So having one more pre-build step wouldn't be too hard. Given the main use case for this feature I'd imagine that's not out of the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a C# script file (.csx) and run it with the `dotnet script` tool from

https://github.com/filipw/dotnet-script

But not a true, valid, C# file no