# procedural programming in C# leads to CS0116 error

Tags: c#, .net, windows, csc

I am following [this](https://youtu.be/bEfBfBQq7EE?t=765) Scott Hanselman's tutorial, where he shows how one could write programs in procedural style without any boilerplate in C#. So I am trying to use the compiler preinstalled on my Windows OS:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
```

to compile a simple Hello World program:

```
// test.cs
System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

using `csc.exe test.cs`

though I am getting the error message:

> error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods

I am wondering if what Scott Hanselman is doing is a new feature not available to the built-in compiler version coming with the operating system, or if there are compiler options to ignore this kind of issues? I could not find any relevant entries when looking into `csc /?`.

**P.S.1.** This is a follow-up to [this](https://discord.com/channels/143867839282020352/143867839282020352/1036150162298519623) Discord question and [this](https://twitter.com/fsfarimani/status/1586600081339416576?s=20&t=eT_sgGK7P3wesgk5WnhbNA) Tweet.

**P.S.2.** seeing responses [here](https://discord.com/channels/143867839282020352/143867839282020352/1036364303101599845) on Discord, it seems to be a new feature.

Comment: Any reason for directly using csc.exe rather than dotnet.exe, like the video you're following does? How are you specifying which version of c# and .net you are targeting?

Comment: @gunr2171 there was a whole discussion [here on Discord](https://discord.com/channels/143867839282020352/143867839282020352/1036150162298519623), where I tried to explain that I care for extreme minimalism and try my best to avoid bloated environments and software installations. The second part of your question, I do not fully understand. May you be kind to elaborate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64399484/c-sharp-9-top-level-programs-without-csproj

Comment: @gunr2171 so you are saying that I should have a `.csproj` file and use the `MSBuild.exe` to compile? what should be the content then?

Comment: Where did I say MSBuild.exe? What runtime are you targeting? Top Level Programs are only available in C# 9 and higher, which is only supported in .Net 5 and higher.

Comment: @gunr2171 now got it. It seems like installing .NET core SDK is unavoidable.

Comment: Minimalism is all well and good, but `csc` as supplied with the .NET Framework itself is essentially deprecated and maintained only for scenarios where code explicitly invokes the compiler for code generation purposes. It shouldn't really be used even for the case where one wants to compile only Framework code (and it says as much when invoked without arguments). Visual Studio Code is pretty minimal. :P

Comment: @JeroenMostert It was a wild effort to see how far I can go with minimalism and still get the feature I want. lessons learned. 

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Minimum SDK version needed to support all language features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/language#minimum-sdk-version-needed-to-support-all-language-features) and [C# language versioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version).